# QDate.currentDate() display formatting

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

I need the date in a regular form.

Here when I use the below code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

date = QDate.currentDate()
print date
```

I get the below output:

```
PyQt4.QtCore.QDate(2014, 5, 23)
```

I want the date to be displayed in '/' or '.'  eg.(5.23.2014)

Please suggest how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdate.html#toString):

```
date = QDate.currentDate().toString("dd.MM.yyyy")
print date
2014.5.23
```

To change:

```
date = QDate.currentDate().toString("MM.dd.yyyy")
print date
05.23.2014
```